# PermissionError Access denied

Tags: python, permission-denied, dataloader, network-drive

while loading some data from a network drive a permission error occurs from time to time and the script terminates with a permission error.

the error occurs in this line :

```
try:
   data =  self.data_file_loader(path)
except PermissionError:
   print('here !!')
```

i assume that the error occurs because of some issues in the network drive. please note that this error happens just from time to time or/and in case of iteration over a large dataset.

a workaround i used is to catch the exception, wait 10 ms and then try again, it worked, but the code isn t really stable besides taking more time to load the data.

```
try:
   data =  self.data_file_loader(path)
except PermissionError:
   print('here !!')
   time.sleep(10)
   data = self.data_file_loader(path)
```

is there a better way to do this  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement some sort of loop with a safety net if the code takes too long. It's pretty much based off what you suggested, but with more 'stability.'

```py
MAX_TRIES = 5
SLEEP_TIME = 10
for _ in range(MAX_TRIES):
    try: 
        data = self.data_file_loader(path)
        break
    except PermissionError:
        time.sleep(SLEEP_TIME)
else:
    # do something to exit the program here, this block is only called when data could not be read
```

Comment: that is working well thanks. i also i extend the waiting time in each iteration so the program waits a bit longer than the first time.